# How to do wildcard yum updates (e.g rhn*) in chef

Tags: chef-infra

How can we do wild card yum updates via Chef yum cookbook.

I want to do:

```
yum update rhn*
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As this is not really an idempotent-able action, you would have to use an `execute` resource. You would probably want some kind of time handling so it doesn't run every time, but the simplest version would be `yum update rhn*`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution from another part of stack exchange. Let me know how it works out for you.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155105/yum-regular-expression-or-wildcard-search